# How to extract element value using webdriverio with mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, webdriver-io

```
browser.getValue('#username').then(function (elementValue) {
    console.log('elementValue : '+elementValue);            
});
```

While using browser object from webdriverio with mocha runner to get element value pass element id then get the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as it is in the webdriverio api docs. Which can be found [here](http://webdriver.io/api/property/getValue.html)

```
browser.getValue(selector);
```

Above should serve your requirement. And it doesn't return any promise so there is no need to chain it with `then`. It returns the value of the attribute `value` in your element.

If you are looking for the value of anything else please feel to comment with your actual requirement. As it is not clear if you are looking for the `value as an attribute` or `value of anything else that element contains`.